# Editing comment help page

Tags: support, comments, editing-help

The [editing help](/editing-help#comment-formatting) gives no mention that commenting when there is one existing commenter will cause them to be notified too.

**Is it the site admin's job to edit something like this in, or would it be down to the community? If so, how?**

---

Note: Whether this page should be changed in this case isn't the purpose of the question, since commented below.

Comment: To be precise, the one existing commenter will only be notified if the _post author_ leaves a comment. For full details see [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019)

Comment: Ahh, ok, that makes the page i linked probably not need the change. I think my question remains though (separate to should it be changed in this case).

Comment: The idea is that if I leave a comment on your question, and you leave a response, it's assumed that you're not talking to yourself so you *must* be replying to me. I'm not sure why this needs to go in the FAQ; it seems quite intuitive. But this @ notification business has been tripping up so many people lately that maybe it's worth spelling it all out... Or disabling it altogether.

Comment: @Cody, i think that since that page explains one instance of where an alert isn't needed it implies that's the only case, which isn't true. Also, for anyone confused about alerts, it's not easy to find a definitive guide.

Comment: Then what *is* the purpose of this question? Seems like I have a hard time understanding your questions; my apologies.

Comment: @Cody, I'm probably not being very clear. I'm trying to ask, whether Jeff, or a site admin etc. is the only one who edits these type of pages, or whether, like all else on SE, the community can edit it (perhaps once they have a lot of rep?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that only developers can change that information. Moderators can edit the FAQ, but it doesn't appear we have edit privileges for the editing/formatting help.

Comment: @Cody. Ok, make that an answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular page can only be changed by Stack Exchange developers. ♦ moderators can change only [a couple of a site's help center pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/295232); the editing help is not one of them.