# How to edit or comment on Editing help

Tags: support, edits, help-center

What is the possible place to comment on or edit the page *[Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)*? I understand from *[Editing comment help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99895/editing-comment-help-page)* that edits are not possible, but I find something missing from the editing help pages.

`<kbd>` `</kbd>` pairs are missing to indicate <kbd>key</kbd> strokes. Plus mentioning that these won't work in the comments editor.

Comment: You mean like [Could the <kbd> tag be added to the editing help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36785/could-the-kbd-tag-be-added-to-the-editing-help)?

Answer (score 10):

Ordinary users can't edit the editing help pages by themselves. Only SE staff can do it.

What we can do, is starting a new [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), explaining exactly what we want to change, and why.

Example: [Could the <kbd> tag be added to the editing help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36785/could-the-kbd-tag-be-added-to-the-editing-help)